# Android ListView scroll to bottom

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I am developing app with chat and I want my `ListView` to scroll to bottom when new message been posted by user and when user was at the bottom of the list and there are new messages recieved. I am using this `ListView`:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:stackFromBottom="true"
    android:paddingBottom="9dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"/>
```

And this method to force scroll when needed:

```
private void scrollListViewToBottom() {
        listView.setSelection(adapter.getCount() - 1);
}
```

But when chat contains element (big text or image) with height bigger than screen height it is scrolling to the top of it. I need my `ListView` to scroll exactly to the bottom, not to the last element.

I tried to use `listView.scrollTo(0, listView.getBottom())` method but the result is very strange - it is scrolling sometimes to the last message + half-screen gap and sometimes to the place where I cannot see any messages.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `android:stackFromBottom="true"` for populating list from bottom to top and add `android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"` for auto scrolling your listview.

You just have to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` and your list will be auto scrolled.

For handling scrolling to absolute bottom in case of large blocks, you can add list items with height of 1 px below every list item so that you will always be directed to end of list no matter what you item's height is.

Comment: `notifyDataSetChanged()` is implemented in only some common subclasses and not available in ListAdapter or other pure implementations.

Comment: I am using `notifyDataSetChanged()` for another purposes and I don't need scrolling every time I execute it. Thanks for the help with 1 pixel size element, that should work. But It is sounds not as 100% good solutions. Are there really no way to do the trick without adding some extra elements?

Comment: Sometimes hack is the only way :)